# Can't get local file link in citation to work

Tags: bibtex, citing, ubuntu, href

## Directory tree

```
.
├── bibliography.bib
├── Makefile
├── reference
│   └── test_reference.tex
└── test.tex
```

## File Contents

### `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{
  reference,
  title={Reference title},
  author={Reference author},
  note={\href{run:reference/test\_reference.pdf}{local file}}
}
```

### `Makefile`

```
all: make_reference make_pdflatex make_bibtex make_pdflatex make_pdflatex
make_pdflatex:
        pdflatex test.tex
make_bibtex:
        bibtex test.aux
make_reference:
        pdflatex -output-directory=reference reference/test_reference.tex
```

### `reference/test_reference.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I am the reference document
\end{document}
```

### `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{reference}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

## Problem

When I run `make all`, the pdfs successfully compile, however when I open the pdf in Sumatra and try to access the local link it shows an error:

> File \wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\code\username\latex_se_question\file:\reference\test_reference.pdf not found

I can tell the path is wrong, which is why it fails to locate the file. However I don't understand why this occurs since I am providing an existing path in my `.bib` file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't test now but at a first glance it looks right. As you are trying to usr a pdf you could try without the run: but as far as remember sumatra simply handles such relative links wrong.

Comment: Hmmm... in that case, would you be able to recommend an alternative self refreshing pdf viewer that I could use in Linix subsystem for windows?

Comment: No, I'm on Windows. But you could open a bug report for sumatra,  it shouldn't inject the file: into the link.

Comment: I can run windows executables from with WSL. Any windows viewer should work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @Ulrike Fischer in the comments, I am doing everything correctly. The local file linking problem is a [known issue](https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/local-hyperlink-problem/2977/5) in version 3.2 of SumatraPDF due to recent MuPDF changes. Currently it looks like the only solution is to revert back to 3.1.2 until the developer fixes the bug.

For what it's worth, I've tried it on 3.1.2 and the hyperlink works as expected.

Comment: I believe I fixed all the linking issues in SumatraPDF and they'll be fixed in 3.3 (or you can use the latest daily build from https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/dailybuilds to get them sooner)

Comment: Did you test my setup above with 3.2? I'd be curious to hear if you got it to work... It certainly doesn't work for me.